# external storage android

Tags: android, storage

Can anyone explain me which is the [external-storage](/questions/tagged/external-storage) in android? I thought that we mean the sd card but after i unmount the card i can still store images in the external storage! The code that i am using is the below:

```
File path = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                        + File.separator + album);
```

Comment: I'm curious to the answer to this aswell. I found [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#isExternalStorageEmulated()), look at the function isExternalStorageEmulated. It looks that phones have the ability to emulate SD cards. I guess this for the purpose of compatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal):

> It's possible that a device using a partition of the internal storage for the external storage may also offer an SD card slot. In this case, the SD card is not part of the external storage and your app cannot access it (the extra storage is intended only for user-provided media that the system scans).

So, you cannot be guaranteed that "external storage" means "on the sd card".